# what is the purpose of zeroconf and avahi?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently, I discovered a process on my ubuntu that was eating away at both processor time and memory, 18% and 10% respectively.  `Avahi-daemon` and I got rid of it along with `pulseaudio`. It seems to me that there is no need for `avahi-daemon` which is a `zeroconf` derivative in itself. If this process caused issues, [isn't well maintained](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=124837), and eats up precious resources then why is it being utilized in ROS? All the way to Hydro, I see [zeroconf](http://wiki.ros.org/zeroconf). I read the discription provided by the ROS wiki, and checked Archlinux for [zeroconf](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ros-hydro-zeroconf-jmdns-suite/) and [avahi](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ros-hydro-zeroconf-avahi/). I still don't see what purpose it serves because I don't see it being a dependency for anything other than [ros-hydro-turtlebot-bringup](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ros-hydro-turtlebot-bringup/).

What purpose does zeroconf and avahi serve when the amount of resources it consumes is detrimental in a resource scarce scenario such as most robot systems, e.g. 7-DOF manipulators, vision-based path planning/navigation, etc?

I am trying to understand what, why, and how of this package/stack. I feel like it should be deprecated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137576/what-is-the-purpose-of-zeroconf-and-avahi?/) by [paresh471](https://answers.ros.org/users/2797/paresh471/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-03-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Later versions of Ubuntu include support for Zeroconf, a technique that allows machines on the same subnet to reference each other using local hostnames instead of IP addresses. So you can use this method if your desktop computer and robot are connected to the same router on a home or office network—a common scenario for both hobby and research robots.

You can use zeroconf to communicate between two systems (say, robot and desktop) to ssh into using just their hostnames.

For eg. If you type $hostname and you get something like "my_robot" you can use this instead of the IP address to communicate between the two pcs. Instead of IP address of both PC just using "my_robot.local" will be helpful.

---

Originally posted by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) with karma: 340 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0